# Making "external" calls through proxy using Apache Camel's Netty4 HTTP component

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty, http-proxy

We use the Apache Camel's `Netty4 HTTP Component` for almost everything on the artifact I have a problem with right now.

The issue is that, a proxy is now required to make external/outbound calls to the Internet...and eventually this is not working. All the calls are getting blocked/rejected — and just for the record, we had the same issue in a different artifact and we were able to circumvent it by using the JVM proxy settings, but this one is using the [Async Http Client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/).

I've tried setting the [proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) at the JVM level by using `http.proxyHost`, `http.proxyPort`, etc., but it didn't work this time.

**Question(s)**: Is there a way to configure any proxy settings within this component? I've been digging inside `org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyHttpConfiguration` to see if there are any relevant settings I can change/use — I'm not completely sure what HTTP client it's used behind scenes and I'm guessing it might be Netty O:)

---

If relevant, (one of) our routes looks like:

```
@Component
public final class Route extends AbstractRouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    super.configure();

    from("{{route.inbound.reports}}") // netty4-http:https://hostname.tld/api/v1/reports
      .choice()
      .when(header(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD).isEqualToIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.GET))
        .toD("seda:get")
        .choice()
        .when(AbstractHelper::isOk)
          .setProperty("source", constant("user"))
          .to("seda:retrieve?timeout={{async.timeout:4500}}")
          .setBody(simple("${property.results}"))
          .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
          .end()
        .endChoice()
      .otherwise()
        .toD("{{route.artifact.reports}}");

    from("seda:get")
      .toD("{{route.artifact.reports}}")
      .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
      .to(exec("analyze"));

    from("seda:retrieve")
      .filter(PredicateBuilder.and(header(Key.ACCOUNT_ID).isNotNull()))
      .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethod.GET))
      .setHeader(Header.API_KEY, simple("{{vendor.api-key}}"))
      .toD("{{route.outbound.reports}}") // netty4-http:https://external-hostname.tld/api/client/reports
      .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
      .choice()
      .when(AbstractHelper::isOk)
        .to(exec("aggregate"))
      .otherwise()
        .to(exec("handleFailure"))
      .end();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no way around this one...or at least, not something I could find within the allowed timeframe.

We ended-up using a different component for all external/outbound calls (that obey the proxy rules); specifically:

- [AHC](https://camel.apache.org/ahc.html) / `camel-ahc`
- [HTTP4](https://camel.apache.org/http4.html) / `camel-http4`